# Working with Realm object directly or map to object class?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, realm

I'm starting learning on how to using Realm in my project, it's great, but i'm seeing some drawback, is the threading problem, Realm's object is not thread safe and can't access it on multiple thread at same time, so whenever i retrieve some data from Alamofire, I map it to `Object`, save it, then bring it back to VC to calculate some changes, then update UI, i want to dispatch the whole part before update UI to dispatch, but then if using Realm directly i have to keep query the `Object` class.

So i'd like to ask if its better to keep querying Realm and work directly with it, or map it to immutable class or struct and use all Realm service in different thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's correct that Realm objects aren't thread-safe and cannot be passed across threads, but it's still quite easy to work with Realm in a multithreaded environment once you get the hang of it. :)

When you commit some changes to a `Realm` instance on a background thread, the equivalent `Realm` instance on the main thread will be automatically updated with those changes on the next iteration of the run loop. If you have any `Results` lists on the main thread (i.e., for displaying Realm objects in a `UITableView`), then these objects will also auto-update with the new objects/changes, and so all you need to do is ensure that your UI refreshes itself to account for these changes.
(NB: For `Realm` instances in other threads, but not the main thread, you need to call `Realm.refresh()` to explicitly pull in those changes.)

If you're working with an explicit Realm model `Object` and want to pass it to another thread to keep working on it there, the easiest thing to do is save it to a `Realm` instance on the current thread, and then re-fetch from the equivalent `Realm` instance on the new thread. In this case, it's recommended that your `Object` schema includes a [primary key property](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#primary-keys) since you can pass this value across threads, and then simply re-fetch the same object by calling `Realm.objectForPrimaryKey()` on the new thread.

For more information, I'd recommend checking out the [Threading section](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#threading) on Realm's documentation page. We're also currently working on a way to make it much easier to be notified when Realm objects are modified in the background, in order to automatically trigger UI updates.

**(Disclaimer: I work for Realm)**

Comment: To just update this answer, as of Realm 2.2 (iOS, macOS, etc) you can now use `ThreadSafeReference` instead of passing the primary key over: https://realm.io/news/obj-c-swift-2-2-thread-safe-reference-sort-properties-relationships/   I would still ask though is there value in mapping Realm objects to Swift Objects if handled safely or is it a total waste of time and should never be considered?